# Since Google Chrome 28 update ALL extensions have stopped working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have just rebooted my machine, restarted Chrome, and been auto-updated to Chrome 28 (with the yellow menu button). And now all my <del>non-Google</del> extensions have stopped working?!

- Cookies 1.7
- Window Resizer 0.7.0.2
- TooManyTabs for Chrome 2.0.0 (Still shows number of tabs on icon)
- ColorZilla 0.5.3

All are the latest version as far as I can tell. Trying to open any of these extensions results in a "**This web page has not been found**" message (as in the screenshot)?!

[image: Chrome 28 - Extensions stopped working]

<del>All the Google-own extensions (Google Mail Checker, Screen Capture and Hangouts) work OK.</del>

Any idea how to make them work again? I can't seem to find anything on the Google, so maybe it's just me?!

**EDIT:** I initially stated it was just the non-Google extensions that had stopped working, however, it is in fact ALL extensions. I naively thought that because the Google extensions still show the correct icon on the toolbar they were OK, but they are not. They report the same error when trying to open them.

Comment: You tried reinstalls them?

Comment: @TiagoCA: Thanks, that would certainly seem to be an obvious thing to try (but I had not!)... and yes, this certainly seems to work with "Window Resizer". However, I am paranoid about losing all the data I have saved with "TooManyTabs", since in order to reinstall I first need to remove it from Chrome. Now, where does TooManyTabs store it's data...

Answer (score 1):

I believe reinstall your extensions should solve your problem.

**Now, where does TooManyTabs store it's data..**

For you export your data stored do:

- Click the icon of `TooManyTabs`.
- Click in `Import / Export`.

  [image: i1]
- On next screen, click in `Export for backup`, if you prefer, save the contents in a text file:

  [image: i2]
- To import the data, follow the steps  screen 1 and click in `Import`:

  [image: i3]

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot open the TooManyTabs extension (by clicking the icon) in order to Import/Export - this requires the extension to be working. When I click the icon I simply get the error as mentioned in the question: "This web page has not been found".

Comment: It seems that in updating Chrome, Chrome deleted the corresponding Extension directories in `%AppData%/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Local Storage`. For the "Too Many Tabs" extension, there should be sub directory called "amigcgbheognjmfkaieeeadojiibgbdp". I was not able to restore the Local Storage for this extension, so I lost all my saved tabs unfortunately. I am beginning to seriously dislike Google Chrome! Anyway, thanks for your help. +1

Comment: Correction: `/Local Storage` above should read `/Extensions`. The `/Local Storage` folder contains the corresponding local storage, but while the local storage looks promising (by it's size and apparent content - SQLite DB), simply copying the local storage files does not appear to restore the data.